# Using If then for entire workbook to look at averages in vba

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to create an If then macro that will allow me to search the entire workbook and bring back the name of the worksheets in `cells(PRow,3)` with values less than or equal to 5 in `range ("B26").value`

So far, the one I have doesn't seem to bring back all the results that meet the criteria.

```
Dim PRow As Long
   PRow = 8
     With wsAddPatient
         For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
            If ws.Range("B26").Value <= 5 _
                And ws.Range("B26").Value <> "" Then
                    .Cells(PRow, 3).Value = ws.Name
                     PRow = PRow + 1
            End If
        Next
    End With
```

Comment: I ran this code and it worked for me. Did you setup `wsAddPatient` as an `Excel.Worksheet` and set it to another worksheet ? the second option is you might have a few workbooks open, in that case it safer (always) to reference to the Workbook with the Worksheets you want this code to run.

Comment: What does it do exactly? Does it get some names but not all that you wish? Does it leave empty rows in column C on `wsAddPatient`? Step through the code using F8 and check what happens.

Comment: It gets some of the names but not all of the names in the workbook. It doesn't leave any empty rows. When I step through it, it highlights sub refresh() and says true = true

Comment: It seems to stop once it hits a work sheet that does not have a value in `Range("B26")` . For example sheet1 to sheet3 has a value. Sheet 4 does not. Sheet5, sheet6, and sheet7 do. However, it will only return values from sheets 1 - 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't try to test the numerical value of a blank cell or one that contains text.

```
Dim PRow As Long
PRow = 8
    With wsAddPatient
        For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
            If IsNUmeric(ws.Range("B26").Value2)  Then
                If ws.Range("B26").Value2 <= 5  Then
                    .Cells(PRow, 3) = ws.Name
                    PRow = PRow + 1
            End If
        End If
    Next
End With
```

Make the test for a numeric cell value separate from any other test as multiple tests will all be evaluated.

This should have resulted in a Type mismatch error is you were trying to compare text; do not use `On Error Resume Next` until you are confident that you have covered all possibilities with proper error control.